# Gitlab api - Is there any api to edit release notes on an existing tag?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to update release notes for an existing tag in gitlab, i am able to do it from UI(by clicking "edit release notes" against a tag) but not able to find any API in tags api documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html

What is the api call for this ?

Answer (score 0):

A tag with release-notes will create a gitlab release. To manipulate those, use the releases api endpoint as specified here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/

Comment: I edited tag and added release notes from gitlab UI but it dd not create any release under deployment -> releases.

Comment: You can also create a release for an existing tag using the API.